# White screen after migrating wordpress from shared webhosting cpanel to VPS

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, migration, vps

I migrated my wordpress blog from shared webhosting to centOS based VPS.

Steps I carried out

- From cpanel zip of public_html
- unzipped that zip in public_html of VPS
- replaced database details in wp-config.php

Observations

- domain.com/wp-admin is loading but I am unable to login inside
- Tried fresh wp installation using wget for fresh installation at domain.com/wordpress/ is also giving the white screen
- In order to check the database tried access mysql in cpanel, it is showing all the posts and user info as well.
- `.htaccess` is already present
- There is nothing in log files as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the WordPress debug function so that blank screen start displaying exact errors, warnings and notices. Based on the displayed errors, you can determine the root cause of white screen of death and fix your WordPress installation.

To enable the debug function, add the following code in your wp-config.php file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Since, you have access to WordPress admin, you should also try un-installing the caching plugin.